# Euler Lagrange equation of a functional on the space of traceless symmetric matrices

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, elliptic-equations

Let $\mathcal{S}_0:\{Q\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}:\text{tr}Q=0 \hspace{5pt}\text{and}\hspace{5pt} Q_{ij}=Q_{ji} \hspace{5pt} \text{for any $i,j=1,2,3$}\}$ and
$$ \widetilde{ \mathcal{E}}(Q)
=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}
\dfrac{1}{2}|\nabla Q|^2
+\left(\dfrac{1}{2} |Q|^2 - \sqrt{6} \text{tr} (Q^3) +  \dfrac{1}{2} |Q|^4\right)dx.
$$
on the space $\mathcal{S}_0$. The Euler Lagrange equation should be
$$ -\Delta Q = -Q+3\sqrt{6}(Q^2-\dfrac{1}{3}|Q|^2Id) -2|Q|^2Q.$$

The question is I do not why I cannot put $Q+\varepsilon R$ as a variation and compute the equation, for $R \in \mathcal{S}_0$, and what correct variation should I use? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think you can't do that?

Comment: Because I have calculated that, the result is different from the correct one, I cannot get the term $-|Q|^2Id/3$.

Comment: Hmmm... I think that should be $-\frac13\operatorname{tr}(Q^2) Id$ instead, i.e., you want to extract the traceless part of $Q^2$.

Comment: yes, $|Q|^2$ and $\text{tr}(Q^2)$ are actually the same thing. So how can I get this term in the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, another way is to use a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)$^1$ to enforce the traceless condition
$${\rm tr}(Q)~=~0.\tag{1}$$
Then the extended functional becomes

$$\begin{align} S[Q,\lambda] ~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\! d^3x\left( \frac{1}{2}{\rm tr}( \nabla Q^t\cdot \nabla Q)+ V(|Q|^2)  -\sqrt{6}{\rm tr}(Q^3)+\lambda {\rm tr}(Q)\right),\cr
|Q|^2~:=~&{\rm tr}(Q^tQ), \cr 
V(s)~=~&\frac{1}{2}s(1+s),\cr
s~\in~\mathbb{R}.
\end{align}\tag{2}$$

The Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation reads

$$ 0~=~\frac{\delta S}{\delta  Q}~=~-\Delta Q^t + 2V^{\prime}(|Q|^2) Q^t-3\sqrt{6}Q^2 +\lambda \mathbb{1}_{3\times 3}.\tag{3}$$

We can determine the Lagrange multiplier by taking the trace of eq. (3):

$$ 0 ~=~-3\sqrt{6}{\rm tr}(Q^2)+3\lambda.\tag{4} $$

Eqs. (3) & (4) lead to OP's sought-for equation.

---

$^1$ A similar idea can in principle be used to impose that the matrix $Q=Q^t$ is symmetric.

Comment: why $V$ is chosen in this way and how can we get (4)?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. why $V$ is chosen in that form?

Comment: That was an effort to try to generalize the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To adapt to the papers provided, let me consider just some open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. As the admissible set of functions, I would suggest something like
$$
M:=\{Q \in C^{2}(\Omega, \mathcal{S}_0) \mid E(Q)< \infty  \}.
$$
On this note, you could also choose a Sobolev space here, but I don't want to check all the emebddings to ensure that the energy is finite in all the scenarios for now. Moreover, we would like to compute the variation in the much bigger ambient space
$$
N:=\{Q \in C^{2}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}) \mid E(Q)< \infty  \}
$$
first. Let us therefore consider a variation $R \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3})$.This is also useful to get rid of any possible boundary terms that will appear when you integrate by parts. I will use the inner product
$$
\langle A,B \rangle= \mathrm{tr}(AB^T)
$$
on the space of matrices.

Then you can compute for any $R \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3})$ at for a function $Q \in M \subset N$
$$
0=\frac{d}{d\epsilon}E(Q+\epsilon R)|_{\epsilon=0},
$$
which is well-defined. Let us examine the variation of the term $\int_{\Omega} | \nabla Q|^2 dx$:
$$
\int_{\Omega} \langle \nabla Q, \nabla R \rangle dx=-\int_{\Omega} \langle \Delta Q, R \rangle dx
$$
Here we integrated by parts and since $R$ has compact support, no boundary term appears.
The terms $\int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{2}(|Q|^2+|Q|^4)dx$ is straightforward.
The last term of interest is $\int_{\Omega} \sqrt{6}\mathrm{tr} (Q^3)dx$.
We note that
$$
\mathrm{tr}(Q^3)=\langle Q^2,Q \rangle,
$$
which has the expansion
\begin{align*}
\langle (Q+\epsilon R)^2,Q+\epsilon R \rangle&=\langle Q^2,Q \rangle+ \epsilon \langle Q^2,R \rangle +2 \epsilon \langle QR, Q \rangle +O(\epsilon^2) \\
&=\langle Q^2,Q \rangle+ \epsilon \langle Q^2,R \rangle +2 \epsilon \langle Q^2, R \rangle +O(\epsilon^2) \\
&= \langle Q^2,Q \rangle+3 \epsilon \langle Q^2,R \rangle + O(\epsilon^2) 
\end{align*}
So in terms of the variation, we would end up with
$$
\int_{\Omega} 3\sqrt{6} \langle Q^2,R \rangle dx.
$$
If I put all terms together now, we get the variational equation
$$
0=\int_{\Omega} \langle -\Delta Q + Q - 3 \sqrt{6}Q^2+2 |Q|^2Q, R \rangle dx.
$$
Now, we can think of $f:=-\Delta Q + Q - 3 \sqrt{6}Q^2+2 |Q|^2Q$ as the $L^2$-gradient of $E$ at $Q$ in the space $N$. But we only need it to be the $L^2$-gradient in the space $M$ and hence we just use the projection
$$
P:N \to M, Q \mapsto Q-\frac{1}{3}\mathrm{tr}(Q)\mathrm{Id}
$$
and calculate $Pf$. Note that all the terms of $f$, except for $Q^2$ are already symmetric and traceless. The term $Q^2$ is symmetric, but not traceless, and hence
$$
PQ^2=Q^2-\frac{1}{3}|Q|^2 \mathrm{Id}
$$
and therefore,
$$
0=Pf=-\Delta Q + Q - 3 \sqrt{6}(Q^2-\frac{1}{3}|Q|^2)+2 |Q|^2Q
$$
as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you may check equation (1.2) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.01440.pdf

Comment: Or equation (2.12) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.10253.pdf, the authors said that the term is the Lagrange multipliers associated with the tracelessness constraint.

Comment: It makes sense in the following way: All the other appearing terms are naturally traceless, expect for the term $Q^2$, which is not necessarily traceless. However, $Q^2- \frac{1}{3}|Q|^2 \mathrm{Id}$ is.

Comment: Yes, but how to make this term appear during the computation?

Comment: The thing I have in mind is, that you have to project $Q^2$ in the direction, which is tangent to $Q$ in the space $\mathcal{S}_0$. I am just wondering how to make this a bit more rigorous and less handwavy.

Comment: Okay, I have an idea. Ill edit my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148709/discussion-between-f-conrad-and-mnmn1993).